# OpenGL - Not able to copy data past a certain size to bound VBO

Tags: c, opengl

I'm still trying to grasp the quirks of OpenGL but it doesn't help trying to learn on OSX which uses OpenGL 4.2 Core, which could be relevant.

All I'm simply trying to do is copy an array of vertex data parsed from an object file, which shows up fine if I iterate through that data, into a bound VBO, however when I use `glGetBufferSubData` to return the contents of the currently bound VBO it shows the data fine for a few dozen lines then starts display what only I can see as corrupted data like so...

```
Vertex: (-0.437500, 0.328125, 0.765625)
Vertex: (0.500000, 0.390625, 0.687500)
Vertex: (-0.500000, 0.390625, 0.687500)
Vertex: (0.546875, 0.437500, 0.578125)
Vertex: (-0.546875, 0.437500, 0.578125)
-------------------vvvvv corrupts here
Vertex: (0.625000, 19188110749038498652920741888.000000, 12125095608195490978463744.000000)
Vertex: (68291490374736750313472.000000, 70795556751816250086766057357312.000000, 0.000000)
Vertex: (4360831549674110915425861632.000000, 4544202249129758853702852018176.000000, 50850084445497733730842814971904.000000)
```

This happens even if I try initializing a buffer of the same or similar size with all zeroes, it gets weird after some arbitrary amount. Here's a snippet to see what I'm doing, but I can't imagine what's going on.

```
// Parse an OBJ file
compositeWavefrontObj com;
parseObjFileVerticies("suzanne.obj", &com);

// Bind a vertex array object
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

// copy vertex buffer data
GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, com.attrib->num_vertices*sizeof(GLfloat), 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, com.attrib->num_vertices*sizeof(GLfloat), com.attrib->vertices);

// Read back data from bound buffer object
GLfloat *vertBuffer = malloc(sizeof(GLfloat) * com.attrib->num_vertices);
glGetBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, com.attrib->num_vertices, vertBuffer);
for (int i = 0; i < com.attrib->num_vertices; ++i) {
    printf("Vertex: (%f,", *(vertBuffer+i));
    ++i;
    printf(" %f,", *(vertBuffer+i));
    ++i;
    printf(" %f)\n", *(vertBuffer+i));
}
printf("\n\n\n");
```

Comment: It looks like you're overrunning the bounds of your buffer(s).  That may follow from the fact that although each vertex has three coordinates, you appear to be reserving space for only one coordinate apiece.

Comment: Why have you incremented `i++;` twice within the loop as well as in the loop control statement? Surely the x,y,z coords are not consecutive in a 1D array?

Comment: @JohnBollinger That was it! For some reason when iterating through the values in the for loop I even noticed that `com.attrib->num_verticies` only stores each 3 dimensional vertex, not each element, so a simple multiplication of that value by three outputs the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems:

`glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, com.attrib->num_vertices*sizeof(GLfloat), 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW);` needs a size in bytes for the whole data.

Because you have X,Y,Z for each vertex, it should be

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, com.attrib->num_vertices*3*sizeof(GLfloat), 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

note the '3'.

Same when you allocate room and read the buffer.

```
GLfloat *vertBuffer = malloc(sizeof(GLfloat) * com.attrib->num_vertices * 3);
glGetBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, com.attrib->num_vertices * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), vertBuffer);
```

Comment: Yep I ended up just going `com.attrib->num_verticies *= 3;`, thank you